# How to download all man pages for read offline?

Tags: arch-linux, man

I like read man pages offline instead of search manual on the web. 
I saw some commands does't have man pages on the machine but exist on internet. For exampe there is no man pace of the `xrdb` command but exist on [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xrdb).

How can I download all man pages for read offline **in man page format(not html or pdf etc)**?

Comment: Are you sure that man page is missing? It is included in the package [according to arch's repo](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/xorg-xrdb/), if you've installed `xrdb`, you should also have its `man` page.

Comment: What is in your `$MANPATH` and are there man pages installed under those directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several sources:

- `git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages`
- http://tldp.org/manpages/man.html
- http://ubuntu-manual.org/?lang=en_US

These are just a few ;)

Comment: [The second one](http://tldp.org/manpages/man.html) leads to a 404 for me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your distribution you can download `-doc` packages (i.e. you can install `xrdb-doc`)

Comment: I am using Arch, there is no package named  with *-doc.